# CMake cannot find QtNetwork library

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, cmake

Im working on QT-CMake based project with multiple shared libraries. Unfortunately when i try to compile class which need QtNetwork, im getting error that QNetworkReply cannot be found. My CMake file looks like this

```
project(Geo CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(Qt4 4.7.3 REQUIRED QtCore QtNetwork)
message(STATUS "Geo module build")

SET(QT_USE_QTNETWORK true)

INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${QT_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_QTNETWORK_INCLUDE_DIR})

ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

set(geo_lib_src google.cpp Tracker.cpp Coordinates.h)
set(geo_lib_headers google.h)

qt4_wrap_cpp(geo_lib_moc ${geo_lib_headers})

add_library(Geo SHARED ${geo_lib_src} ${geo_lib_moc} )
target_link_libraries(Geo ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTNETWORK_LIBRARY})
```

Also, when trying to use that library in other library, Im getting message that cannot resolve function name, but I have there

```
add_dependencies(Core Model Geo)
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Ok, I solved first error. My Include file had QNetwork as include, and the library that I wanted to use Geo, didn't have such link. But I still don't know why linking between so doesnt work...

Comment: didn't need a `${QT_QTNETWORK_LIBRARAY}`  nor `${QT_QTNETWORK_INCLUDE_DIR}` as mentioned in the code. Everything worked after i *just* used `SET(QT_USE_QTNETWORK true)`. Thanks@myky for the impression

Answer (score 0):

Your find_package call looks different from what I see in some project here:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( Qt4 4.6.0 COMPONENTS QtMain QtCore QtGui QtSql QtXml QtNetwork REQUIRED )
```

So I'd try with

```
FIND_PACKAGE( Qt4 4.7.3 COMPONENTS QtCore QtNetwork REQUIRED )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I said before, I solved the problem with non-findable QtNetwork. I was looking at that find_package too, but it  doesn't make any difference in that case. I still have problem with linking.

Comment: I had same error, but I was missing the QT_QTNETWORK_LIBRARY, along with answer’s QtCore QtNetwork line. Works for me now.

Comment: @myky could you figure out a solution? And if so could you brief it as an answer please ?